# AForge not detecting circles which have a line coming out of circle

Tags: c#, aforge

I have detected circles in a particular image by using **AForge** and its working fine. But I am facing One issue. If a `circle` has little line coming outside from a circle like the following image then it does not recognize this circle as a circle.

*Is there any work around how to handle such circle or this is not a circle for **AForge** any more ?*

[image]

I have used the following snippet and its working fine for those
 circles which does not have little line coming out of a circle.

```
// locate objects using blob counter
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter( );
blobCounter.ProcessImage( bitmap );
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation( );
// create Graphics object to draw on the image and a pen
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( bitmap );
Pen redPen = new Pen( Color.Red, 2 );
// check each object and draw circle around objects, which
// are recognized as circles
for ( int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++ )
{
    List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints( blobs[i] );

    Point center;
    float radius;

    if ( shapeChecker.IsCircle( edgePoints, out center, out radius ) )
    {
        g.DrawEllipse( redPen,
            (int) ( center.X - radius ),
            (int) ( center.Y - radius ),
            (int) ( radius * 2 ),
            (int) ( radius * 2 ) );
    }
}

redPen.Dispose( );
g.Dispose( );
```

Comment: Well, I agree with AForge that this is not a circle :) If you are searching for circular shapes you might take a look at circular Hough transforms

Comment: It detect circles of specified radius in an image. While I dont know what would be the radius. It can be any value.